# LNK1104 when declaring a ifstream or ofstream variable

Tags: c++, linker-errors, fstream

I try to open a file with ifstream but as soon as I try to declare a ifstream or ofstream variable I get LNK1104. The header works and the rest of the code also works.

```
#include "sqlite/sqlite3.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

static int createDB(const char* s);
static int createTable(const char* s);
static int insertData(const char* s);
static int showAllTableEntries(const char* s, std::string table);
static int callback(void* NotUsed, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName);
static int updateData(const char* s, std::string table, int id, std::string toChange, std::string newValue);
static int updateData(const char* s, std::string table, int id, std::string toChange, int newValue);

int main()
{
    const char* dir = "C:\\Meins\\Uebungen\\C++\\TryoutDatabase\\TryoutDatabase\\Tryout2.db";
    sqlite3* DB;

    createDB(dir);
    createTable(dir);


    return 0;
}

static int createDB(const char* s)
{
    sqlite3* DB;
    int exit = 0;
    exit = sqlite3_open(s, &DB);
    sqlite3_close(DB);

    return 0;
}

static int createTable(const char* s)
{
    sqlite3* DB;

    std::string sql_statements;
    /*std::ifstream sql_file; // as soon as i add this line to the code i get the LNK1104
    sql_file.open("C:\\Meins\\Uebungen\\C++\\DatabaseMarketAnalysis\\DataBase\\DB_Setup.sql");

    if (sql_file.is_open()) {
        sql_statements = sql_file.get();
    }*/

    // sql statement
    std::string sql = sql_statements;

    try
    {
        // open the database
        int exit = sqlite3_open(s, &DB);

        char* messageError;

        // execute the statement
        exit = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.c_str(), NULL, 0, &messageError);

        if (exit != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error Create Table" << std::endl;
            sqlite3_close(DB);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Table created successfully" << std::endl;
        }
        sqlite3_close(DB);
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to to change the header to fstream.h or .c because I thought it would be a problem with the header. But I have 0 clue what else I could try.

Comment: Show the actual errors (the real ones in the output pane, not the error list) and the full compiler commandline. How did you link to SQLite?

Comment: @Botje 
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: TryoutDatabase, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>TryoutDatabase.cpp
1>C:\Meins\Uebungen\C++\TryoutDatabase\TryoutDatabase\TryoutDatabase.cpp(18,14): warning C4101: 'DB': unreferenced local variable
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Meins\Uebungen\C++\TryoutDatabase\x64\Debug\TryoutDatabase.exe'
1>Done building project "TryoutDatabase.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 15:33 and took 01,563 seconds ==========

Comment: LNK1104 usually means the previously built executable is still running, so the linker cannot write to the .exe file. The error message would tell you which file the linker tried and failed to open.

Comment: @Botje what do mean how i linked to SQLite?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the file `C:\Meins\Uebungen\C++\TryoutDatabase\x64\Debug\TryoutDatabase.exe`, then run the build again.

If Windows doesn't let you delete the file, that may be because the program TryoutDatabase.exe is still running. Kill the program first by closing its window or from Task Manager.

Microsoft documentation of [LNK1104 here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=msvc-170).

Comment: There is no TryoutDatabase.exe in my folder. I tried to clean the build andrun it again but it also did not work.

Comment: I found the problem. My antivirus software is blocking the build because it thinks the program is maleware.